# CodeIgniter/Datamapper: Two one-to-many relationships to the same table not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I'm having this problem with relationships with Codeigniter's [DataMapper](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/).
I have an `Interview` model that has an `author_id` and an `interviewee_id`. They both relate to the user id in the user model.

I've been trying several approaches and none work; this is what I have right now:

```
class Interview extends DataMapper
{
  var $has_one = array(
    'interviewee' => array(
      'class' => 'user',
      'other_field' => 'done_interview'),
    'author' => array(
      'class' => 'user',
      'other_field' => 'written_interview') 
  );
}

class User extends DataMapper
{
  var $has_many = array(
    'done_interview' => array(
      'class' => 'interview',
      'other_field' => 'interviewee'),
    'written_interview' => array(
      'class' => 'interview',
      'other_field' => 'author') 
  );
}
```

How do I let DataMapper know that one relationship will go through `author_id`, and the other through `interviewee_id`?

Comment: It seems there needs to be a `user_id` field necessarily and then for the other relationships I can name the fields however I want. So Changing `interviewee_id` to `user_id` seems to do the drill.

Just in case someone has the same problem out there.

Comment: Please feel free to post an answer to your own question to help others, if that that solved your issue: [answer] . You can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/159834) it after a day or two if no better answers come along.

Comment: Bumping this, hoping that @Nelo will create and accept an answer to remove this from the "Unanswered" queries.

Comment: @Nelo I've added your comment as an answer. If you'd like to improve it, or provide your own answer as an actual answer please feel free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>Quoting [Nelo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1304346/nelo) who answered his question in a comment:</sup>

It seems there needs to be a `user_id field` necessarily and then for the other relationships I can name the fields however I want. So Changing `interviewee_id` to `user_id seems` to do the drill. Just in case someone has the same problem out there